# limit size of img while still responsive

Tags: html, css, markdown

I'd like to have responsive images while limiting their max width or height, and keeping their ratio.
So far I have managed to do only 2/3 of these, everytime one of these conditions is not filled.

I am using markdown hence adding a `div class` around my `![img]` tag is not working: when I build my code it does not render the image and I can see my `![img](https://...` code

What I have tried so far

```css
img {
  max-height:800px;
  max-width:800px;
  height:auto;
  width:auto;
}
```

keep the ratio and limit the size but not responsive

```css
img { 
  width:100%;
  max-width:800px;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 800px;
}
```

responsive and limits the size but does not keep the ratio ok (width is always at max 800px)

and if I don't do anything then it keeps the ratio and it's responsive but pictures are too big

Thanks for your help

Comment: why not use javascript ? and are you talking about aspect ration of image (relative ot it self) or aspect ration of container ?

Comment: @phoenixstudio Why not use js? Because I thought there would be more simple ways to do this, just in css. Didn't think it'd be so annoying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this works?

```css
img {
    max-height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: Hi, not far but it does not really limit the width however :/

Comment: You might be able to make a max-width: 800px and min-width: (for example) 200px

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in a `div` and and `max-height` or `max-width` for the `div` and apply `overflow-hidden`. Or you can add the image as `background-image` and set max-height/width to the Element.
for Example:

```css
.pic{
  max-height:15rem;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
img{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="pic"><img src="https://aisvip-a.akamaihd.net/masters/1030161/3200x1800/selena-gomez-mit-diesem-foto-knackt-sie-beyonces-instagram-rekord.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

Comment: I have many images in my .md file so I cannot add the image as the `background-image` I think. Besides I already tried to put image in a `div` with `max-height` and `max-width` but then `![img]` is not working anymore

Comment: @LaureD try this. I just edited the code :)

Comment: like I said it did not work, my `![img]` tag is not working with a `div` tag around